# SQL Update case when in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I would like to reproduce the following SQL code in pandas. Does anynone have a suggestion?

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column1] =
                  CASE WHEN [Column2] IS NULL
                  AND         [Column3] IS NULL
                  THEN        [Column3]
                       WHEN [Column2] IS NOT NULL
                    AND       [Column3] IS NULL
                       THEN [Column2]
                       WHEN [Column2] IS NULL
                    AND       [Column3] IS NOT NULL
                         THEN [Column3]
                       WHEN [Column2] IS NOT NULL
                    AND       [Column3] IS NOT NULL
                         THEN [Column3]
                       ELSE [Column3]
```

END;

Comment: you should create a reproducible example with expected output, instead of just sharing a code snippet. Have a look at `np.select` and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Glad to answer on your question. I suggested you to change code as below :

```
# Set a default value.
df['Column1'] = df['Column3']
# Set Column2 only when Column2 is not Null and Column3 is Null.
df['Column1'][(df['Column2'] != None) & (df['Column3'] == None)] = df['Column2']
# Other case is set Column3 in default.
```

Hope to get any help from my suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. However it is my intention to create just column 1, in which either the values from column 2 or column 3 are inserted depending on the conditions (e.g. depending on whether one, both or none of the values in column 2 and 3  are null/nan )

Comment: Hello, Did you find any way to solve this question?

Comment: The barbaric way: I merged the columns, added a delimitor and split them in half..